# 'analyse the scalability' or 'performance analyse'?

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentences.

> 1. It is also **important to analyse the scalability** of the proposed solution.
> 2. It is also **important aspect of performance analyse** of the proposed solution.

I am not sure, which sentence is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance and scalability are two different concepts with a bit of overlap (e.g. something may perform well but be completely unscallable, single user, single project, period.) so you're asking two different things here.

The first sentence is correct, but the second has some mistakes.

> It is also **an** important aspect of performance **analysis** of the proposed solution.

**to analyse** is a verb, so "aspects of [a noun], **analysis**. Alternatively you might try to use the gerund form:

> It is also **an** important aspect of **analysing** the performance of the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is the correct one